# angularjs filters unique filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

How to enable or disable the radio buttons according to available options in the array

---

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.directives','ui.filters']);


app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $filter,$http) {
  $scope.pageNumber = {};
         $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/rainnaren/20355aea389ba6f7bfb801ecb52774d6/raw/4482a3d9f5a0cc3e73720a11e0e2b60c085519c0/data.json').then(function(data){
          $scope.data = data.data;
          
          angular.forEach($scope.data.products,function(key,value){
            angular.forEach(key.productAttributes,function(k,val){
              // console.log(key.productAttributes)
              //   $scope.brandsGroup = uniqueItems(key.productAttributes, val);
              // console.log($scope.brandsGroup)
            })
          })
        });
//         var uniqueItems = function (data, key) {
//       var result = [];
//       for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
//         var value = data[i][key];
//         if (result.indexOf(value) === -1) {
//             result.push(value);
//         }
//     }
//     return result;
// };
  
  $scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.pageNumber;
  }, function() {

    $scope.v = function(event,d) {
      var count = Object.keys($scope.pageNumber.productAttributes).length;
      console.log(count);
      if ($scope.data.variantAttributeses.length === count) {
        $scope.x = $filter('filter')($scope.data.products, $scope.pageNumber);

      }
    };

  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"> </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{pageNumber}}
  <div ng-repeat="d in data.variantAttributeses | unique:d">
    {{d.name}}
    <div>
      <form ng-repeat="dg in data.products    | filter:pageNumber ">
             <label><input ng-change="v()" type="checkbox" ng-model="pageNumber.productAttributes[d.name]" ng-true-value="'{{dg.productAttributes[d.name]  }}'" ng-false-value="''">{{dg.productAttributes[d.name]    }}</label>
        </form>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div ng-repeat="data in x | filter:pageNumber:true">
      {{data.brandProductId}}
    </div>
  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

here the unique filter is not working what is the solution to do this i tried the angular ui filters but in my case it is not working anyone provide me the custom filter for that.

in this the field name is also dynamic . so how to filter the duplicates from the json
[here is my working code](https://plnkr.co/edit/AHZD3HbO0R5oA6OtZt3T?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The logic for writing the function that determines what is disabled isn't trivial (I just tried for about 15 minutes) ultimately you can use ng-disabled and set a property on the "option" in the data so that it gets reflected in the view, something like

```
ng-disabled="d.disabled"
ng-change="checkDisabled()"
```

in the checkDisabled you'd have to run the logic to determine which options actually get the "disabled" attribute added to them for use by ng-disabled here.

Also to keep the filtered data on scope can use:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in data.products | filter:pageNumber as filtered">
```

then you will have a `$scope.filtered` with the filtered products.  The trick is you need to go through all radio options and for each one you need to search all products and see if any product doesn't match the option value.  If it matches any value then disabled for that option =false if it matches no values of any or the filtered products then it's disabled=true.

Comment: let me try this